# Sort multidimensional array with null values last

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I want to sort multidimensional array values from not null to null. I want to sort my multidimensional array if the address fields like street, post numbers are null then they should display in last page.

Comment: This question is not a good fit for Stack Overflow because it does not contain a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function array_sort($array, $on, $order=SORT_ASC) {

    $new_array = array();
    $sortable_array = array();

    if (count($array) > 0) {
        foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
            if (is_array($v)) {
                foreach ($v as $k2 => $v2) {
                    if ($k2 == $on) {
                        $sortable_array[$k] = $v2;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $sortable_array[$k] = $v;
            }
        }

        switch ($order) {
            case SORT_ASC:
                asort($sortable_array);
            break;
            case SORT_DESC:
                arsort($sortable_array);
            break;
        }

        foreach ($sortable_array as $k => $v) {
            $new_array[$k] = $array[$k];
        }
    }

    return $new_array;
}
```

something along the lines of that works for me 
(more or less copy pasted from http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about PHP but in general I would say you need to slice your array so to divide the `null` set from the not `null` set, then sort the not `null` set based on your criteria and then merge it with the `null` set.