# Multidimensional array sort on multiple keys

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

Hi I've been using the `array_sort()` function found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198835/sorting-multidimensional-array) for some time to sort results from multiple APIs but now I have the need to sort by two keys simultaneously.

The two keys I need to sort on are `deal_score` DESC and `date_start` DESC

The properties of this array are as follows.
Record 2 has the highest `deal_score` so should come first
Records 0 and 1 have the same `deal_score` but `date_start` is higher on record 1 so the final order of results should be 2, 1, 0

Here's an example array which has been trimmed down for readability.

```
       [0] => Array
            (
                [db_id] => 414314
                [date_start] => 2012-04-17
                [deal_score] => 81.3
                [deal_statements] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 49.85
                    [1] => 2.11
                )
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [db_id] => 414409
                [date_start] => 2012-04-20
                [deal_score] => 81.3
                [deal_statements] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 28.2
                    [1] => 21.41
                )
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [db_id] => 1345923
                [date_start] => 2012-04-17
                [deal_score] => 85
                [deal_statements] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 18.1
                    [1] => 22.16
                )
            )
```

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sth. like this should do:

```
foreach ($data as $key => $row) {
    $score[$key] = $row['deal_score'];
    $dates[$key] = $row['date_start'];
}

array_multisort($score, SORT_ASC, $dates, SORT_ASC, $data);
```

3rd. example on http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php pretty much explains it.

Cheers.